# How do I put a SimplePie Enclosure Link into an Array

Tags: php, arrays, simplepie

I am attempting to parse an RSS feed which uses media enclosures. I am using SimplePie and I have been able to parse it, and make all the needed elements appear on the page.

But I am writing a plugin for a CMS and I need to put those elements into an array. All are working fine, except the $item->get_enclosure().

I should say, that in the array, what is returned is a string of gibberish. I need it to return the *url to the file*.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    // Get Enclosure
        $enclosures = array();
        $item_enclosures = $item->get_enclosures();
        if ( ! empty($item_enclosures))
        {

  foreach ($item_enclosures as $enclosure)
  {
    if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure())
        {
          $enclosure->get_link();
        } else {
        $enclosure->get_title();
        }
    }
  }


        $items[] = array(
            'item_title'        => $item->get_title(),
            'item_link'         => $item->get_permalink(),
            'item_date'         => $item->get_date('U'),
            'item_content'      => $item->get_content(),
            'item_img'          => $item->get_enclosure(),
            'item_description'  => $item->get_description(),
            'item_categories'   => $categories,
            'item_authors'      => $authors
        );
    }


    return $items;
```

Does anyone know how to make the 'item_img' return a link to the file, rather than what seems to be some kind of encoded string of characters.

Answer (score 0):

From http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_enclosure/get_link

```
$link = $item->get_enclosure()->get_link();
```

would seem to do what you want.